# In Java, what's the most readable way to do array bounds-checking?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of varying length, and I'd like to read from a fixed position.  If the position is out of bounds, I'd like to read a null, instead of throwing.  I can of course do something like

```
if(theArray.length <= colNum){ result = null; }
else{ result = theArray[colNum]; }
```

but that seems kind of inelegant.  I'd like to be able to make a one-liner or simple function call that acts like `theArray[colNum]` except returns `null` instead of throwing an out-of-bounds exception.  Is there something like that I'm overlooking?  Am I overthinking this?

Comment: @ahenderson Then he would still get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java).

Here is a one-liner:

```
result = ((colNum > theArray.length - 1) || (colNum < 0)) ? null : theArray[colNum];
```

Comment: You'll get an exception when `colNum == theArray.length`.

Comment: @Jesper so it should be "<=" instead of "<".  Just as a little comment, *I* would also put the variable that changes more often (colNum) before the other item being compared to (theArray.length), "result = (colNum >= theArray.length) ? null : theArray[colNum];", because it seems to me it reads better, but that is just readability and style.  Of course they're equivalent.

Comment: It's still a really long line, but technically a one-liner.  I was hoping for something more like `theArray.forgivingGet(N)`.  If only I could monkeypatch Java! :-/

Comment: @Coderer You could easily make a method that you could pass the array and the index, you'd call it with `result = safeGet(array, index);`.

Comment: Jesper: I might end up doing that just for clarity.  I had hoped such a thing would already be in `Arrays` or Commons `ArrayUtils` or *something* -- guess I'll roll my own...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you think is more readable, but you can always use the raised exception:

```
public String read(String[] array, int index)
{
    try
    {
        return array[index];
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be little rough way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what "elegant" means to you?, There are several of ways for doing it, if you want short code, use the [ternary operator](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm):

```
result = theArray.length <= colNum ? null : theArray[colNum];
```

Also, you can do the read, and try/catch an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

```
try { 
    result = theArray[colNum];
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
    result = null;
}
```

And you can encapsulate any of the both in a method, so your invoking code will look like:

```
result = readFromArray(theArray);
```

Comment: No, I was slow typing them because I was searching the links to "decorate" the answer